# can i put button and textbox and listview in one activity?

Tags: android, listview, button, textbox, client-applications

I am new to android and now i am developing client side application in android. I want to know can I put button , textbox and listview in an activity class.Usually we extends class from Activity but for listview extends from ListActivity.

thanks

Comment: yes you can do it in ListActivity also....

Comment: hi sujit, can you show me example or site or code? thank

Answer (score 0):

The ListActivity class is convenient when you want a single ListView to consume the screen, however a ListView does not require a ListActivity. You can place the ListView within your layout.xml and use it there as well.